# grep a file to read a key:value

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a file `file.txt` which has various `key:value` pairs. While reading a particular `value` from file, more than one lines are printed. Please help me in correcting my logic below.

**INPUT_FILE**

```
cat file.txt

NAMES:1234-A0;5678-B0;3456-C0
1234-A0:1234_12345678_987
```

**DESIRED_OUTPUT**

`1234_12345678_987`

**MY_CODE**

`cat file.txt | grep -w 1234-A0 | cut -f2 -d ':'`

**OUTPUT**

`1234-A0;5678-B0;3456-C0
1234_12345678_987`

Please let me know what's wrong in the above command (?) and what should be the correct command to get `desired output`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is right tool for this as your data is delimited by a common character and structured in columns and rows. You may use this awk command:

```
awk -F: '$1 == "1234-A0"{print $2}' file
```

```
1234_12345678_987
```

Answer (score 1):

First,

> Please let me know what's wrong in the above command

When you wrote `cat file.txt | grep -w 1234-A0` 
it should be `grep -w 1234-A0 file.txt`
(I mean it's useless to pipe from `cat` into a command that can directly read file,
plus you're eating some piece of precious ressources while making your script sub-optimal)
That being said, you asked for lines with word "1234-A0" ...and that's exactly your output!
Now try the following and note down the differences:

- `grep ':1234-A0' file.txt` (you should have the first line)
- `grep '1234-A0:' file.txt` (you should have the second one)
- `grep '^1234-A0' file.txt` (second line too)

Add more lines, with "1234-A0" randomly elsewhere in the file and rerun the examples above
to see the differences.

Last,

> what should be the correct command

Once you give the right pattern, you can now pipe to cut as you did:
`grep '^1234-A0:' file.txt | cut -f2 -d:` for example.

AWK language is another way to go, more concise, but not for now as you are
still learning BRE (also found in `sed` and `vi`, whereas `awk` uses ERE)

Comment: Thanks @gildux for the detailed explanation. This really helped me.